# AI model deployement in STM32

Tags: c, tensorflow, stm32

I have an AI model on python

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

# Sample data (features and labels)
features = [
    [0.2, 0.5],
    [0.4, 0.7],
    [0.6, 0.3],
    [0.8, 0.9]
]

labels = [0, 1, 0, 1]  # 0: Negative class, 1: Positive class

# Convert lists to TensorFlow tensors
x = tf.constant(features, dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = tf.constant(labels, dtype=tf.float32)

# Build a simple neural network
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(x, y_true, epochs=50, batch_size=2)

# Make predictions
y_pred = model.predict(x)
print("Predictions:", y_pred)
```

that I downloaded and deployed on the STM32 ide but I don't know how to use it with C

this is the code I tried but it seems like it's not working and output_value gives the same random value every time

```
int i=0;
  AI_ALIGNED(4) float in_data[AI_NETWORK_IN_1_SIZE_BYTES / sizeof(float)];
  AI_ALIGNED(4) float out_data[AI_NETWORK_OUT_1_SIZE_BYTES / sizeof(float)];
  AI_ALIGNED(4) ai_u8 activations[AI_NETWORK_DATA_ACTIVATIONS_SIZE];

  ai_handle network_model = AI_HANDLE_NULL;
  ai_buffer ai_input[AI_NETWORK_IN_NUM] = AI_NETWORK_IN;
  ai_buffer ai_output[AI_NETWORK_OUT_NUM] = AI_NETWORK_OUT;

  ai_network_params ai_params = {
      AI_NETWORK_DATA_WEIGHTS(ai_network_data_weights_get()),
      AI_NETWORK_DATA_ACTIVATIONS(activations),
  };

  ai_input[0].size = 2;  // Assuming your model takes 2 floats as input
  ai_input[0].data = AI_HANDLE_PTR(in_data);
  ai_output[0].size = 1;  // Assuming your model produces a single float as output
  ai_output[0].data = AI_HANDLE_PTR(out_data);

  // Load input data (modify this based on your model's input requirements)
  in_data[0] = 0.0f;
  in_data[1] = 0.0f;
  float output_value = 0.0f;

  // Create and initialize the neural network
  if (!ai_network_init(network_model, &ai_params)) {
      i=1;
      printf("Error initializing the neural network\n");
  }

  // Run the neural network
  ai_network_run(network_model, ai_input, ai_output);

  // Retrieve output data (modify this based on your model's output)
  output_value = ((float*)out_data)[0];

  printf("Value of output: %f\n", output_value);

  // Cleanup and destroy the neural network
  ai_network_destroy(network_model);
```

I want to know how can I use that python model in C or any python model generally in C after deploying it into STM32 ide